# set a default callback to react setState() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, functional-programming

I want to see if I can call a function for every state update of a component. Since react setState() accepts a callback as seconds parameter, is there a way to invoke a function on every state change?

I tried something but didn't go well. You can check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/302rlpmjwp).

Please correct me if something's wrong in the way I am binding.

Comment: Hey, check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/0py6yo9vjv

Comment: @igorves I know that it can be achieved that way. My question was to see if there is a way to bind it to every setState directly using javascript's bind function instead of using any react lifecycle methods.

Comment: got it, but it's not the best way: to add some extra functionality directly

Comment: agreed. Didn't work that well too. I couldn't bind it either case. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `componentDidUpdate` to check if the state was updated and call the function within.
Note that `componentWillReceiveProps` is being deprecated.

### UPDATE 2021

You can now use the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in order to have a callback function for whenever the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

The callback you pass as the second parameter is meant to access the current state and return the new one. You can create a wrapper function to add functionality to the state change, something like:

```
const onStateChange = (...) => {
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
    this.setState(...);
};
```

Then whenever you want to change the state, call this function with the added behaviour. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gliadbar I know that it can be achieved by adding an intermediate function. I just wantedto know if there's a way to bind it to react's setState directly

Comment: @klvenky You should usually avoid adding functionality directly, you can never know what side effects you might cause

Comment: agreed, just wanted to know either if it's valid or not :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of overriding the callback of `setState` to be executed on every state change, you can simply use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method in react

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   //compare this state and prevState and take action here
}
```

Or you can write a function that executes a function and a setState

```
_setState = (updatedObj) =>{
     this.setState(updatedObj, this.callback)
}
```